# Rudin Def. 1.13: lim sup subsequence property of extended real numbers sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Definition 1.13: (Walter Rudin: Real and Complex Analysis)

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence in $[-\infty;+\infty]$, and put $b_k=\sup\{a_k,a_{k+1},...\}$ and $\beta = \inf \{b_1,b_2,...\}$.

The following properties are easily verified: First, $b_1\geqslant b_2\geqslant ...$ (**this is by monotonicity of the supremum**) so that $b_k \longrightarrow\beta$ as $k\longrightarrow\infty$ (**this is by
"Convergence of a monotone sequence of real numbers": [lemma 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lemma_1)**);
secondly, there is a subsequence $\{a_{n_i}\}$ of $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_{n_i} \longrightarrow \beta$ as $i\longrightarrow \infty$, and $\beta$ is the largest number with this property.

I proved the first part is proved(the comments are in parenthesis).
In the second part I stuck a little bit.

I think the subsequence may be defined constructively the following diagonal way:
$$x_n := \min\{\max\{a_1,...,a_{1+n}\},...,\max\{a_n,...,a_{n+n}\}\}\longrightarrow \beta \mbox{ as } n\longrightarrow \infty$$
Since
$$y_{k,q}:=\max\{a_k,...,a_{k+q}\} \longrightarrow b_k\mbox{ as }q\longrightarrow \infty$$
and
$$z_{m}:=\max\{b_1,...,b_m\} \longrightarrow \beta \mbox{ as } m\longrightarrow \infty.$$
But it is hardd to actually prove it.

My question:

1. Are my statements true/false or unnecessary?
2. How to prove that $\beta$ is the largest number with this property?
3. Is there an easier way to prove it and how?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to search for information on this if you realize that $\beta$ is called the limit supremum.

For the existence of a subsequence converging to $\beta$ (the limsup), the idea is to find a subsequence that stays "near" the $b_k$'s. By definition of $b_k$, given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $n \ge k$ such that
$$
a_n \le b_k < a_n + \epsilon.
$$
In particular,
$$
\lvert a_n - b_k \rvert < \epsilon.
$$

To construct the subsequence of $(a_n)$, start with $n_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\lvert a_{n_1}-b_1 \rvert < 1.
$$
You can justify the existence of $n_1$ as above. Then, given $n_{k-1}$, there exists $n_{k} > n_{k-1}$ such that
$$
\lvert a_{n_k}-b_{n_{k-1}+1} \rvert < \frac{1}{k}.
$$
The subsequence constructed as such converges to $\beta$ (I'll leave the details here for you).

To prove that $\beta$ is the largest number for which there is a subsequence of $a_n$ converging to $\beta$, proceed directly. That is, suppose $(a_{n_k})$ is a convergent subsequence. Then, by definition of the $b_k$'s,
$$
a_{n_k} \le b_{n_k}.
$$
Therefore, the limits satisfy
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k} \le \lim_{k\to\infty} b_{n_k} = \beta.
$$